# How would I create a structure that allows me to define multiple objects with multiple values?

Tags: c++, structure

I need to create a structure that allows me to define an x number of points (the number of points changes at run time) in a 3-D coordinate system. Each point has an x, y, and z value. So far I have a basic structure like this, but I need it to be able to have multiple points, each with their own values.

```
struct point {
        int point_num;
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `point_num` is a non-contiguous but unique identifier you could use `std::map<int, point>` and remove the identifier from the struct.  That way you get O(log(N)) lookup using the index.

If `point_num` values are unique and contiguous, use `std::vector<point>` - again the id field is superfluous, as the location in the vector provides an indexing value for you.

Read up a bit on STL, especially [containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/), before you go much further.

Answer (score 2):

Use a container. `std::vector<point>` would be the simplest. If there are no duplicate points, use `std::set<point>`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `vector`, the standard C++ container:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<point> points;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; ++i) {
        point p = {i, ..., ..., ...}; // Obtain coordinates somehow (with stdin, rand(), or whatever you want)
        points.push_back(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you need to, you can wrap a `vector` in a struct or a class.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably create a struct that represents one point, and have an array or vector of points.

But, if from some reason it has to be one struct, you can do:

```
#include <vector>
struct point {
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
};

struct x_points {
        vector<point> v;
};
```

Or you can define `point` inside `x_points`:

```
#include <vector>
struct x_points {
        struct point {
            double x;
            double y;
            double z;
        };

        vector<point> v;
};
```